# Sending a bunch of images from an android phone to a PC

Tags: java, c#, android, image, client-server

I'm working on an app that suppose to transfer images from an android phone to a PC in a server - client architecture (the java (android) code is added below).The photos suppose to pass through a bytearray.  I'm having a hard time to figure out how to create a protocol over TCP that will be able to pass my images without loss of information and also be able to pass the META-DATA of the images such as the image name, extension, size, maybe META-DATA size (if needed?). I would really appreciate your
help becuase I'm kind of new to C# and writing a client-server, especially one that suppose to transfer images of some sorts of extensions.

```
private void makeTCPConnection() {
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("10.0.2.2");
            //create a socket to make the connection with the server
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 8000);

            try {
                //Sends the message to the server
                OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
                File dcim = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
                if(dcim == null)
                    return;
                File[] pics=dcim.listFiles();
                int count=0;
                if(pics != null){
                    for(File pic:pics){

                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pic);
                    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
                    byte[] imgbyte = getBytesFromBitmap(bm);
                    output.write(imgbyte);
                    output.flush();
                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
             Log.e("TCP","S:Error",e);
            }finally {
                socket.close();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("TCP","C:Error",e);
        }
    }

    public byte[] getBytesFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,70,stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }
```

Comment: Are you using Android as client and PC as server. Socket program to transfer image from phone to PC ?

Comment: Yes. Ive added the code.

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18583248/sending-png-image-file-from-server-desktop-to-client-android-via-socket-prog

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to write a small [REST web service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service#REST)?

This approach would have some advantages:

- HTTP (human-readable) is used as a protocol, so you don't have to come up with an own protocol.
- JSON (human-readable) can be used transmit data. (Maybe not for photos, but for metadata.)
- There are plenty libraries for the client and server side.
- Client and server can be written in different languages.
- In some languages a REST web service can be created with just a few lines of code.
- The REST web service can be written first and can be tested (with a REST client), before writing the client application.
- More REST endpoints can be added easily. (Maybe you build a simple upload first and later add more endpoints to upload metadata.)

For Android I can recommend [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit) as a REST client. And if you want to use Java on the server side, I would recommend [Spring/Spring Boot](https://spring.io/). (How-to guide for a REST web service in Spring Boot: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)

Comment: Ive already built a web platform that will be used as web interface for my app. All I need is the client server part to be completed. But Im stuck with creating  a protocol that will transfer the meta data and then the data. Can anyone help?

Comment: What language and frameworks/libraries did you use to build your web app?